# How can I check existance and update an object in nested array in mongodb/mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongodb-query

We're trying to build a REST API with node.js and typescript for an Inventory Management Web App. Our Records>Stocks documents(nested arrays) are under the Branches collection.

- **Records**: Keeps data with bucket pattern. This means branches can only have one record document in a day.
- **Stock**: Stocks could have types like **'TRANSFER' or 'DAILY'**. A branch could have only one **'DAILY'** stock-entry and many **'TRANSFER'** stock-entry in a Record.

We have a stock updating requirement. Our **Branches Collection** sample document like below.

```
{
"phones": [
    "Lorem"
],
"_id": 2,
"name": "Üsküdar",
"address": {
    "city": "İstanbul",
    "address_line": "Cinali Sk. No:14 Selamiali 34664 ",
    "district": "Lorem"
},
"owner_id": 38,
"region_id": 12,
"totals": {
    "stock": {
        "P": -63,
        "K": 23,
        "U": -73
    },
    "sale": {
        "P": -28,
        "K": 82,
        "U": -36
    },
    "material": {
        "Kutu": 29,
        "Garnitur": 37,
        "Spatula": -55
    }
},
"records": [
    {
        "delivery": {
            "P": -18,
            "K": -69,
            "U": -15
        },
        "stocks": [
            {
                "time": "10:45",
                "quantity": {
                    "P": [
                        15
                    ],
                    "K": [
                        9
                    ],
                    "U": [
                        11
                    ]
                },
                "explanation": "Günlük Stok Girişi",
                "type": "DAILY"
            }
        ],
        "sales": [
            {
                "time": "Lorem",
                "quantity": {
                    "P": [
                        "Lorem"
                    ],
                    "K": [
                        "Lorem"
                    ],
                    "U": [
                        "Lorem"
                    ]
                },
                "explanation": "Lorem"
            }
        ],
        "material": [
            {
                "time": "Lorem",
                "quantity": {
                    "Kutu": -68,
                    "Garnitur": 42,
                    "Spatula": 4
                },
                "explanation": "Lorem"
            }
        ],
        "date": "16-09-2020"
    }
],
"orders": [
    {
        "date": "Lorem",
        "borek": {
            "quantity": {
                "P": 6,
                "K": 77,
                "U": -25
            },
            "status": "Lorem"
        },
        "material": {
            "quantity": {
                "Kutu": -43,
                "Garnitur": 29,
                "Spatula": -70
            },
            "status": "Lorem"
        }
    }
]}
```

Our endpoints like below, it gets branch_id and creates a request with req.body `{"quantity": {"P": [11],"K": [4],"U": [4]}}`

```
branchRouter.post(
  '/:branchId/daily-stock',
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { branchId } = req.params;
    const { quantity } = req.body;

    const timestamp = moment().tz('Europe/Istanbul');
    const date = timestamp.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    const time = timestamp.format('HH:mm');
    const explanation = 'Günlük Stok Girişi';
    const type = 'DAILY';
    const stockEntry = new Stock({ time, quantity, explanation, type });
    const recordEntry = new Record({ date, stocks: [stockEntry] });

    try {
      await Branch.findByIdAndUpdate(
        branchId,
        {},
        {
          new: true,
          projection: {
            'records.stocks': 1,
            'records.date': 1,
            // records: { $slice: 5 },  // to get first 5 array object
            records: { $elemMatch: { date: date } },
            'records.stocks.type': 1,
          },
          // arrayFilters: [{ 'records.stocks.type': { $eq: 'DAILY' } }],
        },
        async function (err: any, result: any) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(501).send('Branch cannot be updated!');
          } else {
            if (result) {
              if (result.records.length === 0) {
                await Branch.findByIdAndUpdate(branchId, {
                  $push: { records: recordEntry },
                });
                res.status(200).send({
                  message:
                    'No record found for today, it will be creating with daily-stock',
                  record: recordEntry,
                });
              } else {
                const entries = result.records[0].stocks;
                if (entries.some((stock: any) => stock.type === 'DAILY')) {
                  // TODO Update data by req.body, you can use something like $replacewith
                  await Branch.findByIdAndUpdate(branchId, {
                    'records.0.stocks': {
                      $cond: {
                        if: { $eq: ['$type', 'DAILY'] },                        
                        then: { $push: { 'records.$[].stocks': stockEntry } },
                        else: { $push: { 'records.$[].stocks': stockEntry } },
                      },
                    },
                    // $addToSet: { 'records.$.stocks': stockEntry },
                  });
                  res.status(200).send({
                    message: `Today's records and daily-stock exist, Daily-Stock Entry Updating...`,
                    record: result.records[0],
                  });
                } else {
                  await Branch.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    branchId,
                    { $push: { 'records.$[].stocks': stockEntry } },
                    {
                      projection: {
                        'records.stocks': 1,
                        records: { $elemMatch: { date: date } },
                      },
                    }
                  );
                  res.status(200).send({
                    message: `Today's records exists but not Daily-Stock, Daily-Stock Entry Inserting...`,
                    record: result.records[0],
                  });
                }
              }
            } else {
              res.status(404).send({ error: 'Branch not found!' });
            }
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
  }
);
```

***The question is how would we update 'DAILY' stock entry for today If we have already it?***

Actually, the scenario is a little bit hard. We need to use a conditional structure, but **$cond, $replaceWith, $push, etc.** don't give an idea to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found, answer is here

```
const dailyStockUpdatedBranch = await Branch.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: branchId },
                {
                  // $pull: {
                  //   'records.$[record].stocks.$[stock]': stockEntry,
                  // },
                  $set: {
                    region_id:
                      'records.$[record].stocks.$[stock].quantity.P[0]',
                  },
                },
                {
                  arrayFilters: [
                    { 'record.date': date },
                    { 'stock.type': 'DAILY' },
                  ],
                  projection: {
                    'records.stocks': 1,
                    'records.date': 1,
                    totals: 1,
                  },
                }
              );
```